# Where would Saccharomyces cerevisiae be found in highest concentrations in environment?

Tags: microbiology, mycology

I have bakers asthma specifically to 'Sc' yeast, and know to avoid bakeries, breweries, etc...

I have figured out to not disturb rotting leaf piles, and fermenting bark mulch. Where else?

What percentage higher are concentrations in say Florida, as opposed to New York state?

Comment: interesting question.  aerosol yeast and fungi must vary a log with the weather, humidity and this sort of change in condition.

Answer (score 6):

[Here is a link to an interesting article](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com.ezproxy.liv.ac.uk/store/10.1111/j.1365-294X.2012.05732.x/asset/mec5732.pdf?v=1&t=hd7f4efn&s=d7918ad3c34791c5b30dc5f9c6750f46b0a990f4) which reports a survey of wild isolates of *Saccharomyces cerevisiae* in China.

> Wang, Qi-Ming, et al. (2012) Surprisingly diverged populations of Saccharomyces cerevisiae in natural environments remote from human activity. Mol Ecol 21: 5404-5417

A relevant quotation from the article:

> In addition to grapes and oak tree (Quercus spp.) bark, S. cerevisiae was successfully iso-lated from a variety of damaged fruit collected in orchards or markets in different provinces of China; from the bark of different deciduous trees; forest soil and rotten wood collected in primeval, original secondary and planted forests located in different regions covering temperate, subtropical and tropical climate zones from northern to southern China. Unexpectedly, the success rate of S. cerevisiae isolation from fruit samples (6.5%) was lower than that from tree bark (16.5%), soil (10.8%) and rotten wood (9.2%) samples. S. cerevisiae was more frequently isolated from forest soil samples (success rate 13.7%) than from orchard soil samples (success rate 9.1%). Among the fruits giving positive S. cerevisiae isolation, grape samples showed the lowest success rate.

Table S2 in the supplemental information records isolates as follows:

```
climatic zone    sites   isolates
__________________________________
tropical           5       20
subtropical        2       14
temperate          13      51
```

Superficially, from this it looks as if there would probably be little difference between New York state ([humid, continental](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Climate_of_New_York)) and Florida ([humid, subtropical](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Climate_of_Florida)).